# How to call .class for a class with type parameter? E.g. List<String>.class

Tags: java, spring

To start with an easy example, calling `List<String>.class` results in compile error, I can just call `List.class` to achieve my purpose.

Recently, I am doing things related to Spring REST template. I have to input a class object for the `getForObject` method. I have such a class: `Foo<T>`.

The result is, I cannot provide `Foo<Bar>.class` as one of the arguments.
Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it, because at runtime there *are* no types, due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

When the program executes, there is only `List.class` - there is no such thing as `List<String>.class`, just provide a `List.class`.

If you really need to pass the class of the type, change your method to accept a `Class<T>` parameter and pass `String.class`.

Comment: Would you please explain the last sentence a bit more? Change your method to accept a `Class<T>` parameter and pass `String.class` ?

Comment: Class<T> represent Class object of type T. Since you can't pass Foo<T>.class, you can either pass Foo.class or the tuntime type T, for example String.class.

Comment: example:  public <T> void someMethod(Class<T> clazz);  Read up on generics, but basically, anywhere in the method you can use T to represent the type in variable declaration (ie List<T>) or instantiation (ie new ArrayList<T>()) .  But, due to type erasure, there's no way at runtime to know what T is, so you pass in Class<T> which enforces that the class you pass is the one that represents the type T.